# Cannot push file & folder to shared hosting

Tags: git, yii2, kartik-v

I develop my app with Yii 2. I use widget select2 at my form. But when i try to push my app to shared hosting, some files and folder in vendor\kartik-v\yii2-widget-select2 not push. What must i do?

Comment: Have u added your file before?

Comment: You never push `Vendor` folder to your repo or live, although it is already added to `.gitignore`  you run the 
`composer update` after pushing all the code, dont know if you are using any repository or not.

Comment: i got error when i try composer update:

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 494927872) (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps below:

1. Make sure that those files/folders are not listed in the `.gitignore` file.
2. Add those files/folders to `index` with `git add <files/folders>` or if you want to add all content of the mentioned folder then `git add vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2`.
3. Type `git status` to see whether those files/folders have been actually added to `index` or not.
4. Make a commit: `git commit -m "message of commit"`
5. Finally push the commit to your hosting: `git push origin` -- suppose that the alias of the hosting is `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

You never push `vendor` folder to your repo or live, although it is already added to `.gitignore` you run the `composer update` after pushing all the code, dont know if you are using any repository or not.

For running composer, if you are on a shared hosting you might get the `memory_limit` error so use the following way to run the composer.

1. Run the command `which composer` to find the path of the composer installed. this will give you the path where the composer is installed like `/home/user/bin/composer`, copy the path.
2. Then use `-d` switch with `php` to specify the memory limit while running the command, for example `php -d memory_limit=512M /path/to/composer update`

Note : there is a possibility that you get errors for `allow_url_fopen`, in case you receive this error while updating the composer use `-d` to add another command like 
`php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d memory_limit=512M /path/to/composer update`